# How to integrate HTML pages into WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, html-content-extraction

I have a page in HTML(index.html),  and a folders named images, css, js that used in it.

Now i have to do this in WordPress. Is there any plug in to convert Html to WordPress or any other way to do this in WordPress? Please help me.. i'm a beginner in WordPress.

Comment: You need to implement your html as wordpress theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure of a direct way to implement a HTML page into a WordPress theme, but if you have made `header` and `footer` files for your website, then all you need to do is convert them to make them WordPress compatible.

You should refer to the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org).

You can also go for any of the WordPress frameworks listed [here](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/wordpress/free-frameworks/).

A WordPress theme is easy to understand if you know basic PHP. It has a set of files like

- header.php // header file
- footer.php // footer file
- index.php // the index file
- page.php // for your WP pages
- single.php // for your WP posts
- and some other files

Go through the codex and it shouldn't take long to get the hang of it.

Answer (score 2):

You need http://themematcher.com/

It'll automatically take your site, styles, images etc and create a wordpress theme for you. Check it out

Answer (score 1):

Theres really only three ways:

1. Hire a freelancer
2. Convert manually by referring to http://codex.wordpress.org/
3. Use an automated converter. Best one on the market is
   https://htmltowordpress.io

Answer (score 0):

here is the link for complete solution of this problem.
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-integrate-htmlphp-page-to-wordpres?replies=6

make sure to add 
/*
Template Name: Custom Page Template
*/
 piece of code in index.php page at top in your selected theme folder, not on ur main index.php file.